# Compiling lunatic python on windows

Tags: python, c, lua

I'm trying to compile lunatic python on windows with minigw. The command is as follows:

```
 gcc.exe -shared -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL src\luainpython.c src\pythoninlua.c liblua.a
 libpython27.a -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\LUA\include
```

This gives me undefined reference errors. But I cannot find any lua api change reference with what should I replace these.

```
src\luainpython.c:350:14: warning: 'LuaObject_Type' redeclared without dllimport
attribute after being referenced with dll linkage [enabled by default]
C:\Users\Wiz\AppData\Local\Temp\cccm0nAN.o:luainpython.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined
     reference to `lua_strlen'
C:\Users\Wiz\AppData\Local\Temp\cccm0nAN.o:luainpython.c:(.text+0x557): undefine
    d reference to `_imp__LuaObject_Type'
C:\Users\Wiz\AppData\Local\Temp\cccm0nAN.o:luainpython.c:(.text+0xc3a): undefine
    d reference to `luaL_getn'
C:\Users\Wiz\AppData\Local\Temp\cccm0nAN.o:luainpython.c:(.text+0x1036): undefin
    ed reference to `luaopen_loadlib'
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bi
    n/ld.exe: C:\Users\Wiz\AppData\Local\Temp\cccm0nAN.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in s
    ection `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The -DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL option is inappropriate.  It should only be used when you build Lua, not when you compile code that *uses* Lua.

Comment: @HansPassant I did remove the LUA_BUILD_AS_DLL and managed to corrections to most of the errors, but it didn't work anyway. Will be lookin more in to it a bit later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original Lunatic-Python codebase has many known problems -- the build issue you're running into above being one of them. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the original author is still maintaining this project -- if the last modification date [**here**](https://code.launchpad.net/lunatic-python) is any indication.

If you're still trying to get it to work I would highly recommend going with one of the more recent forks. In particular, the [**Lunantic-Python fork at github**](https://github.com/bastibe/lunatic-python) incorporates many of my fixes improvements.

Getting back to your question, many of the undefined references are due to improper forward declaration in the headers or because of defined macros that cause the forward declare to be incorrect. For example, the original `luainpython.h` contains:

```
PyAPI_DATA(PyTypeObject) LuaObject_Type;
```

In windows, after preprocessing it expands into:

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) PyTypeObject LuaObject_Type;
```

In other words, the linker's going to try and find the definition of `LuaObject_Type` from an import library. This is of course wrong since that new type is created and implemented by lunatic in `luainpython.c`. The proper prototype should be `extern PyTypeObject LuaObject_Type;` instead.

Also note that `luaopen_loadlib` is deprecated in Lua5.1 which explains the other undefined reference you're getting. In fact, lunatic-python's usage of the following are all deprecated:

```
luaopen_base(L);
luaopen_table(L);
luaopen_io(L);
luaopen_string(L);
luaopen_debug(L);
luaopen_loadlib(L);
```

and should be replaced with this instead:

```
luaL_openlibs(L);
```

Comment: In the end I just managed to move on in my project without lunatic python, but the link and explanation will probably help me anyway in future, so thank you for your answer. :)